# Populating a table skeleton using data in different tex files

Tags: tables, tabularx

Throughout my thesis, I use the following table format:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[]{natbib,har2nat}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor = darkblue,citecolor=darkblue,urlcolor=darkblue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\usepackage{multirow}

\title{tables}
\author{}
\date{March 2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{lccc}
    \toprule
          &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{2-4}          & (1)   & (2)   & (3) \\
    \midrule
          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{A. Men} \\
\cmidrule{2-4}          &       &       &  \\
          &       &       &  \\
          &       &       &  \\
          &       &       &  \\
          &       &       &  \\
          &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{2-4}          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{B. Women} \\
\cmidrule{2-4}          &       &       &  \\
          &       &       &  \\
          &       &       &  \\
          &       &       &  \\
          &       &       &  \\
          &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{2-4}          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Covariates} \\
\cmidrule{2-4}    TE    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \\
    DD    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \\
    DD2   & No    & Yes   & Yes \\
    DD3   & No    & No    & Yes \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Now, I want to populate the table with results in different tex files. For example, I have the following two tex files (for men and women, respectively):

```
ETR -0.445  -0.414  -0.434  
(0.094) (0.076) (0.057) 
Observations    722 722 722 
R-squared   0.27    0.46    0.66    

ETR -0.445  -0.414  -0.434  
    (0.094) (0.076) (0.057) 
Observations    722 722 722 
R-squared   0.27    0.46    0.66
```

Is it possible to input these results in the skeleton table?

Comment: I guess answers to you question strongly depend on which editor you employ. Please do tell which editor you use.

Comment: I am using Texpad.